# F# infinite stream of armstrong numbers

Tags: f#, stream

I'm trying to create an infinite Stream in F# that contains armstrong numbers. An armstrong number is one whose cubes of its digits add up to the number. For example, 153 is an armstrong number because 1^3 + 5^3 + 3^3 = 153. so far, I have created several functions to help me do so. They are:

```
type 'a stream = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a stream);;

let rec upfrom n = Cons (n, fun() -> upfrom (n+1));;

let rec toIntArray = function
    | 0 -> []
    | n -> n % 10 :: toIntArray (n / 10);;

　
let rec makearmstrong = function
    | [] -> 0
    | y::ys -> (y * y * y) + makearmstrong ys;;

let checkarmstrong n = n = makearmstrong(toIntArray n);;

let rec take n (Cons(x,xsf)) =
   match n with
   | 0 -> []
   | _ -> x :: take (n-1)(xsf());;

let rec filter p (Cons (x, xsf)) =
    if p x then Cons (x, fun() -> filter p (xsf()))
    else filter p (xsf());;
```

And finally:

```
 let armstrongs = filter (fun n -> checkarmstrong n)(upfrom 1);;
```

Now, when I do `take 4 armstrongs;;`, (or any number less than 4) this works perfectly and gives me [1;153;370;371] but if I do `take 5 armstrongs;;`nothing happens, it seems like the program freezes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the issue is that there are no numbers after 407 that are the sums of their cubes (see http://oeis.org/A046197), but when your code evaluates the equivalent of `take 1 (Cons(407, filter checkarmstrong (upfrom 408)))` it's going to force the evaluation of the tail and filter will recurse forever, never finding a matching next element.  Also note that your definition of Armstrong numbers differs from, say, Wikipedia's, which states that the power the digits are raised to should be the number of digits in the number.

Comment: I would also point out that your definition of `'a stream` type doesn't allow specifying empty stream.